# Get selected point(s) indices on zoom in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to be able to zoom upon one or more point and get the associated `Y` value(s) for that point. So far I have got this, but without any success: http://jsfiddle.net/animeshb/8rdkb7t4/3/

```
var pointValue = this.series[0].data[index].y
```

I am not able to find the index of the selected point or selected points. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this might not be the best way, but I got it working for a single point by doing the following:

```
var pt = Math.ceil(event.xAxis[0].min)
pointValue = this.series[0].data[pt].y;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/animeshb/8rdkb7t4/5/

So, to capture multiple points, I have expanded the above a bit further like this:

```
var minpt = Math.ceil(event.xAxis[0].min);
var maxpt = Math.ceil(event.xAxis[0].max);
var distance = maxpt - minpt;
if (distance == 1) pointValues.push(this.series[0].data[minpt].y);
else {
    for (var i = minpt; i < maxpt; i++) {
        pointValues.push(this.series[0].data[i].y);
    }
}
pointValues.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item);
});
return false;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/animeshb/8rdkb7t4/7/

The problem with this is, I get values even if I drag the selector above or below the points/markers.

I will continue to explore this and will update here if I have a solution.